# LibGdx - Use two styles in one TextButton

Tags: java, libgdx

How can I use two styles in the same TextButton?

```
 TextButton rankedGame = new TextButton(bundle.get("play"), buttonPlayStyle);
```

I would like to add a sub-heading to "PLAY" in a smaller font, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Button is a subclass of a Table, so you can add another label to it for your secondary text, like this:

```
Label subheadingLabel = new Label("test", skin, "mySmallFont");
rankedGame.getLabelCell().row().add(subheadingLabel);
```

On the second line you can chain on methods for table cells to align it, such as using `.expandX().center()` to center it, for example. And if your subheading is wider than the main text, you could do the same to the main text to center it:

```
rankedGame.getLabelCell().expandX().center();
```